# C++ LInker error (Visual Studio C++ 2010)

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors

I tried to create empty project for Visual Studio.

```
// OpenGL1.cpp : main project file.
// #include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Having configured these dependencies:

> opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;olepro32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies);C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl;

And I got this error:

> .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl.obj'

Can you explain why this happens and how to remove the error?

Comment: linker inputs and include paths are different things

Comment: Most probably `gl.h` provides some static context object, that is instantiated and needs the GL library for linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dependencies" refer to the *filenames of libraries* which the linker should use, not to include paths. Include paths are for the compiler, not for the linker.

You must first tell the linker where to find the OpenGL library file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

And then, as a dependency, you specify only its name, not a full path. In this case, `opengl32.lib`.

Comment: Where should the library file be located?

Comment: @JohnBoe: somewhere close to `gl.h`. I wouldn't know without looking it up myself.

Comment: I found it C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib ... but why VS does not know about this directory? Is this not a default directory?

Comment: @JohnBoe: This, I do not know :)

Comment: I have removed /ASSEMBLYDEBUG  from linker and it compiled successfully now. Thanks.

Comment: But I think it was something with the dependencies. This is correct: opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;olepro32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies);